# Unexpected output from SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table looks like this

```
column1 column2   timestamp
-----------------------------------------
 1      1         2017-09-05 15:09:57.811
```

Executing this query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(column1) column1, SUM(column2) column2, roundDate, 
    COUNT(*) recordCount 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         column1, column2, 
         DATEADD(second, FLOOR(((DATEDIFF(second, '20000101', DATEADD(MINUTE, 480, timestamp)) / 2592000) * 2592000)), '20000101') AS roundDate 
     FROM 
         tablename 
     WHERE 
         (column1 > 0 OR column2 > 0) 
         AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 480, timestamp) BETWEEN '2017-09-01 07:30:00' 
                                                 AND '2017-09-30 07:30:00'  
         AND CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, 480, timestamp) AS time) BETWEEN '07:30' AND '19:30') t 
GROUP BY 
    roundDate 
ORDER BY 
    roundDate
```

Note: `2592000` is the interval value, it is changeable based on user selection (1 minute, 3 minute, 10 minute, weekly, monthly and quarterly)

Current result

```
column1   column2  roundDate                  recordCount 
----------------------------------------------------------
45        627      2017-08-29 00:00:00.000    212
480       334      2017-09-28 00:00:00.000    830
```

As you can see the `roundDate` in result is wrong because it back to August and detected some days from September. It is supposed to follow the where clause condition `BETWEEN '2017-09-01 07:30:00' AND'2017-09-30 07:30:00'` and return one record only.

Expected result

```
column1   column2  roundDate                  recordCount 
-----------------------------------------------------------
525       961      2017-09-29 00:00:00.000    1042
```

What is wrong in this query?

Comment: what database is this for? "sql" isn't enough to identify syntax needed

Comment: yes, this is sql database. is there anything not clear?

Comment: SQL is a language,  "SQL Server" is a database from Microsoft. The tag `sql` is NOT an identification of the database you are using.

Comment: It is sql server database  using sql language

Comment: the main issue here is the interval value, it is the value that causing this error. How to fix that?

Comment: What is the correct roundDate for `2017-09-05 15:09:57.811`? (or. put another way, *you have not displayed the wanted result*)

Comment: roundDate of `2017-09-05 15:09:57.811` is `2017-09-05 00:00:00`

Comment: I have updated question to show expected result

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter on calendar month you should do that. What your query is currently doing is dividing time into 30 day slices since 2000-01-01. I expect 2017-08-29 is the start of one of those slices.